# Split rich contentEditable div into two divs at caret

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a rich content editor where each paragraph is its own content editable div element. When the user presses return, I want to split the existing div, which contains HTML, in two.

```
var pos = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
var allContents = target.innerHTML;
var before = allContents.substring(0, pos);
var after = allContents.substring(pos, allContents.length);
            
article[key].content = before
article.splice(key + 1, 0, {content: after})
```

The problem is that this splits the content as if there were no HTML. For example,

> "What *happens* **when** I press ^return?"

Where the caret is at ^ becomes:

> "What *ha*"

And:

> "ppens **when** I press return?"

It is measuring the offset as if the innerHTML doesn't exist.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection